# how check whether the GPS Sensor currently reading signal?

Tags: android, gps

How to check if the GPS is reading a signal. I have written a code to check whether the GPS is enabled or not.

```
private void systemService() {
    locMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if(!locMgr.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
     AlertDialog.Builder noGps = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     noGps.setMessage("GPS is off. Please turn it on and restart your Application.");
     noGps.show();
     }// end of if        
}// end of systemsService();
```

But, even when it is enabled it takes few minutes or seconds the GPS sensor to receive the signal.

Myy question is: how to check if the GPS sensor is currently receiving a signal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't. 
You can use `runOnFirstFix` to use location data when available, and also define an update interval with [requestLocationUpdates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29).